# Statistical power to avoid bias

Tags: statistical-power, bias

I’m analysing how doctors classify an disease (disease / no disease).
In this connection, I have some images of people with known diseases, however, they were classified as not having the disease. I want to show these pictures to the doctors again, to see if they are now able to see that in fact there is disease. However, I think it would introduce bias to only show the wrongly classified images (classified as no disease, when there was a disease). Therefore, I was thinking of adding some correctly classified images (classified as no disease, and no disease was present).
I would like to make some sort of power calculation to find out how many correctly non-disease images I should add to the dataset.
Does anyone have any kind of experience/tips regarding this?